# Set Key For Queue

Tags: java

I am trying to create a priority queue where the key will be Total() = getCost() + getTax(). I am setting the priority queue up like this:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(50);
```

I have been looking up things about priority queues and I read about comparator but I am still lost on the whole thing. How do I go about using the method below to set the key for my priority queue?

Method that gets the Total:

```
public int compareTo(Node y){
    if (getCost() + getTax() > y.getCost() + y.getTax())
        return 1;

    else if (getCost() + getTax() < y.getCost() + y.getTax())
        return -1;

    return 0;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Comparator directly when initializing `PriorityQueue`:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<Node>(50, (x, y) -> {
if (x.getCost() + x.getTax() > y.getCost() + y.getTax())
        return 1;

    else if (x.getCost() + x.getTax() < y.getCost() + y.getTax())
        return -1;

    return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go this solution:

```
PriorityQueue<Node> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(50, Node::compareTo);
```

PriorityQueue constructor can take an initial capacity and a Comparator object. Since Java 8, this object can be replaced with a lambda or a method refernce (as in my example).

Comment: Is there a way that does not involve the ::? I have never seen that before and would like to stick to what  I know for now

Comment: @GBall You can replace that by `(n1, n2) -> n1.compareTo (n2)`.

Answer (score 0):

The `PriorityQueue` will automatically use the "natural ordering" of the objects, when they implement the `Comparable` interface. It will use the `compareTo()` method of your `Node` class to pick the next `Node` object. You don't need to provide an additional `Comparator` class which compares the `Node` objects for you.

```
public Node implements Comparable<Node>
{
    // [...]

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node y){
        if (getCost() + getTax() > y.getCost() + y.getTax())
            return 1;

        else if (getCost() + getTax() < y.getCost() + y.getTax())
            return -1;
        return 0;       
    }
}
```

Then simply create a use a `PriorityQueue` object.

```
PriorityQueue<Node> queue = new PriorityQueue<Node>();
queue.add(node1);
queue.add(node2);
queue.add(node3);

Node next = queue.poll();
```